# unicode letter in quotes appearing after body tag in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, unicode

A unicode letter (﻿) is appearing in quotes after the body tag in chrome only. It's not showing up in any other pages. It is a wordpress site. But, the (﻿) is not in view source file, but I can see it with my chrome inspector.

my Code

```
<body class="page page-id-90 page-template page-template-daily_activity page-template-daily_activity-php logged-in no-touch sidebar full resp overlap">&#65279;


<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="description" content="A health diary to manage and track your stress and health and avoid burnout">
<meta name="keywords" content="Digital monitoring of health, Health Diary, Health Diary with statistics, Stress Diary, Sleep Diary, Stress management, Preventive stress Management, Self-assessment of health, Tools for preventive stress management, Health monitoring, stress, happiness">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://myhappiness.se/wp-content/themes/child-ultra/images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://myhappiness.se/wp-content/themes/child-ultra/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<!-- Pie-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://myhappiness.se/wp-content/themes/child-ultra/css/circliful.css">
<style type="text/css">
.row1 {
    background: #ebebeb;
    width:100%;
    min-height:240px;
    height:auto; padding-bottom:10px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    float:left;
}
.grph_container{ width:auto; padding-left:10%}
</style> 

<!-- end -->
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="http://myhappiness.se/xmlrpc.php">
<title>Daily activity – MyHappiness</title>
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//s.w.org">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="MyHappiness » Feed" href="http://myhappiness.se/feed/">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="MyHappiness » Comments Feed" href="http://myhappiness.se/comments/feed/">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="MyHappiness » Daily activity Comments Feed" href="http://myhappiness.se/daily-activity/feed/">
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `&#65279;` that follows `<body class=...>...</body>`? It does not look like it should be there. It's the same as [0xFEFF byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: `<meta charset="...">` belongs into `<head>` not `<body>`.

Comment: Thanks. it worked